# Characters and Strings with C

Tags: c, string, char, type-conversion

I'm working on restful client written in C. It is very simple, I just have to send by post a person name (John, Sam, Muhammad, Whatever...) which I write on terminal.

My whole code is working fine but I have some issues with conversion char or strings, to send by post.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void) {

CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;

int x = 1;
unsigned char m;

while (x != 0) {
    printf("Opcao 1 para incluir nova pessoa\n");
    printf("Opcao 2 para listar pessoas\n");
    printf("Opcao 0 para sair\n");
    printf("Selecione a opcao: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);

    if (x == 1) {
        printf("Nome da pessoa: ");
        scanf("%s",&m);

        curl = curl_easy_init();
        if(curl) {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "localhost/wsRest/index.php/novo/" );
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
            res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
            if(res != CURLE_OK)
                fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                  curl_easy_strerror(res));
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
}

curl_global_cleanup();
return 0;

}
```

I need to find a way to put the name written on variable 'm' in curl_easy_setopt() function, concatenated with my URL, but I have no idea how to do it, and the examples that a I found cant even read the URL to another variable...

How can I do it?

Thanks you everyone!

Comment: `m` is a single character. You need a char array instead.

Comment: To concatenate use `strcat` or `strncat`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work the way you expect:

```
scanf("%s", &m);
```

`m` is an `unsigned char`, the scanf `%s` modifier will attempt to read a string, write it to the pointer you feed it, and null-terminate it. For any non-empty name, it will write to invalid memory (if you're lucky, this should crash).

Indeed, you passed a pointer to a character, but there's only space for 1 character.

You should use an array instead, for example:

```
char m[512];
/* ... */
scanf("%s", m);
```

Note that this places an upper bound of 511 on the name length. If you expect longer names, increase the buffer size.

**UPDATE**:

You can prepend the URL by doing:

```
char m[512];
int idx = sprintf(m, "localhost/wsRest/index.php/novo/");
/* ... */
scanf("%s", &m[idx]);
```

Then pass `m` as the url.

This works by first storing the URL path in `m`, and then reading the input string into the rest of the buffer. `sprintf(3)` returns the number of characters written, so `idx` is the offset of the first position after the URL path.

If you want to append instead, then `scanf("%s", m)` and then use `strcat(m, "localhost/wsRest/index.php/novo/")`.

Again, this assumes that the name + the URL size is less than 511.

Comment: Right.. and for concatenate this variable with my URL 
"localhost/wsRest/index.php/novo/" + m
How can I do it?

Comment: Prefer `fgets(&m[idx], sizeof m - idx - 1, stdin);` over the `scanf` to prevent buffer overflows on evil input.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need an array to hold the name entered by the user. Change this

```
unsigned char m;
```

to this

```
char m[1000];
```

Next, you need an array to hold the URL

```
char url[1200];
```

Then you can use `sprintf` to append the name to the URL

```
sprintf( url, "localhost/wsRest/index.php/novo/%s", m );
```

And finally pass the `url` to the `setopt` function

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
```